# a debilitating war

Tags: meaning

What is a debilitatig war?

> At that moment, however,a debilitating war broke out which undermidned the existing powers and opened up to opporunities to the new entrants.

(The Silk Roads)

According to the dicitionary, debilitate means enfeelbe or weaken.
I don't understand how I translate it in the context.

Comment: Hi Mankak,  I've noted there are quite a few typos in your recent questions.  Do you have a spell checker for English.  It is worthwhile getting one. Spelling is one part of English that computers often do better than people.

Comment: I think the dictionary meaning is correct.  "it is a war that enfeebled or weakens" the nations that are fighting.

Answer (score 2):

Debilitate literally means to take away ability. The war between the powerful nations took away their ability to protect or care for themselves, allowing smaller nations to enter the struggle for power.

Comment: Exactly. A nation at war uses up its own armaments and other resources, and suffers damage from attacks by its enemy. Making it weaker/more feeble.